# Web Facets in Intellij web resource directory wrong

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

As you can see Intellij keeps suggesting the resource directory is src/main/webapp.

However, my resources configuration is

```
            <resources>
                    <resource>
                            <directory>resources</directory>
                    </resource>
            </resources>
```

and

```
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

Yet, intellij will as in the picture keep suggesting src/main ... and from what ass is this **webapp** directory being pulled out of?

Very annoying. This thing has never worked with Intellij.

And you can't edit it either, because it will be overwritten as you need to configure it with maven.

I've even added:

```
    <webappDirectory>assets</webappDirectory>
    <webResources>
            <webResource>assets</webResource>
    </webResources>
```

but still the src/main/webapp directory is suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of a Maven project IDE follows Maven rules. In Maven [web resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) are configured under `<webResources>` tag. Make sure you have something like this in pom.xml:

```
<webResources>
...
    <resource>
        <directory>web/resource/path></directory>
    </resource>
...
</webResources>
```

For instance:

```
   <warSourceDirectory>resources</warSourceDirectory>
```